# Unknown error occurring when send put and delete requests (posts are fine)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So When i send a post request to my end point Everything works. However when i send put and delete requests i got problems in the response.  Here is my code for one of my endpoints (put)

THE RESPONSE EXACTLY:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot PUT /api/auth/username</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
 router.put('/username/:id', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res) => {
      const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, {new: true})
      if (!user) return res.status(404).send('User not found.')

      res.send('User sucessfully updated.')
}))
```

Please help this BUG IS A PAIN.

Comment: STILL NO SOLUTION

Comment: can you show whats in `asyncMiddleware ` and also show the requets body?